# unique index for subdocument property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to set an unique index for the property `userID` in my subdocument User, with is used as an array in my Class schema. The index should be for each Class and not a global index for all classes.

So Class A should for example be able to have the userIDs [1,2,3,4] and Class B [2,3,4,7,9].
What should not be allowed is: Class A [1,2,2,3]
The following query gives me an exception:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: app.classes index:
>   _users.userID_1 dup key: { : 1.0 }

**Query**

```
db.classes.update(
  { _id: ObjectId("597f6864694ff43ddca09eaf") },
  { $push: { _users: {userID: 1}}} 
);
```

**Schema**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    userID:             {type: Number, unique: true}, 
    // ...
};

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var classSchema = new Schema({
    _users:         {type: [userSchema]},
    // ...
});

mongoose.model('Class', classSchema);
```

**db.class.find({});**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "597df15eb0b0bd17c985df05",
    "_users": [
      {
        "_id": "597e9d373f01d64b66b9249f",
        "userID": 1,
      },
      {
        "_id": "597f6892694ff43ddca09eb0",
        "userID": 2,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": "597f6864694ff43ddca09eaf",
    "_users": [],
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you add the index after you already had data in the first class? If so, that is not allowed in mongodb.

Comment: No, the index was added first.

Comment: In the mongoshell if you use db.collection.getIndexes() do you see an index that correctly describes the index you're trying to use?